# Maven cannot resolve AWS-CDK dependencies (Java)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to build a Maven multi-module project which uses the AWS CDK `software.amazon.awscdk` package.

However, I consistently get a `DependencyResolutionException` error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project github-api-infrastructure: Could not resolve dependencies for project pixee:github-api-infrastructure:jar:dev: Failed to collect dependencies at software.amazon.awscdk:aws-cdk-lib:jar:2.17.0 -> software.constructs:constructs:jar:[10.0.0,11.0.0): No versions available for software.constructs:constructs:jar:[10.0.0,11.0.0) within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

The error says it cannot find a `software.constructs` package with the right version, but it [should exist on the Maven repositories](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.constructs/constructs).

I've tried updating my Maven version, clearing the Maven cache and rebuilding, but I get the same error.

This is the only module that fails to build, so I don't expect it to be a problem listed in [`DependencyResolutionException`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException) documentation such as the connection to the remote repository being misconfigured or a network problem.

The build works on my teammates computers, but not on mine. I'm not sure what could possibly be the issue, since we're on the same-ish Java (I'm on 17, they have 18) version and same Maven version.

Not familiar with the Java ecosystem, please let me know if additional clarification is needed.

Multi-module `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>x</groupId>
  <artifactId>github-api</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>dev</version>

  <modules>
    <module>testutils</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>functions</module>
    <module>infra</module>
  </modules>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>x-libs-release</name>
      <url>https://x.jfrog.io/artifactory/mailman</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>x-libs-release</name>
      <url>https://x.jfrog.io/artifactory/mailman</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>x-libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>https://x.jfrog.io/artifactory/mailman</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <fmt.goal>format</fmt.goal>

    <versions.fmt-maven-plugin>2.18</versions.fmt-maven-plugin>
    <versions.maven-shade-plugin>3.2.4</versions.maven-shade-plugin>
    <versions.maven-compiler-plugin>3.8.1</versions.maven-compiler-plugin>
    <versions.maven-surefire-plugin>3.0.0-M4</versions.maven-surefire-plugin>
    <versions.maven-failsafe-plugin>2.22.0</versions.maven-failsafe-plugin>

    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <versions.jackson>2.13.2</versions.jackson>
    <versions.log4j>2.17.1</versions.log4j>
    <versions.awssdk>1.12.99</versions.awssdk>
    <versions.junit-jupiter>5.7.0</versions.junit-jupiter>
    <versions.hamcrest>1.3</versions.hamcrest>
    <versions.mockito>4.3.1</versions.mockito>
    <versions.hsqldb>2.6.1</versions.hsqldb>
    <versions.mariadb>2.6.0</versions.mariadb>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${versions.maven-compiler-plugin}</version>
          <configuration>
            <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.7</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${versions.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
          <configuration>
            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.spotify.fmt</groupId>
          <artifactId>fmt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${versions.fmt-maven-plugin}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>format-java</id>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>${fmt.goal}</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${versions.maven-failsafe-plugin}</version>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>**/IT</include>
            </includes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>ci</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env.CI</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <fmt.goal>check</fmt.goal>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Infra module `pom.xml` (only module that fails):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>x</groupId>
        <artifactId>github-api</artifactId>
        <version>dev</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>github-api-infrastructure</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <versions.awscdk>2.17.0</versions.awscdk>
        <versions.constructs>10.0.91</versions.constructs>
        <versions.mybatis>3.3.10</versions.mybatis>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x</groupId>
            <artifactId>github-api-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x</groupId>
            <artifactId>github-api-testutils</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.log4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-cdk-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.awscdk}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.constructs</groupId>
            <artifactId>constructs</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.constructs}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-migrations</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.mybatis}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.mariadb}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.junit-jupiter}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.junit-jupiter}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.hamcrest}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.mockito}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${versions.hsqldb}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>resource-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>x</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>github-api-functions</artifactId>
                                        <version>${parent.version}</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                        <destFileName>github-api-functions.jar</destFileName>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Create a runnable JAR -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${versions.maven-shade-plugin}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>**/Log4j2Plugins.dat</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify.fmt</groupId>
                <artifactId>fmt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 17.0.4, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.72-microsoft-standard-wsl2", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Java Version:

```
openjdk 17.0.4 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4+8-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on WSL 2.

---

Update:
I tried rebuilding it yesterday and the build was successful with no errors. I didn't change anything. Perhaps the package repositories were updated?

I tried rebuilding it today and I get the same error as before. I wonder if it's an error due to how Maven is configured locally on WSL. But why would it affect just this package?

I'm thinking now the dependency resolution fails because of something on JFrogs side.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was with my permissions on JFrog. I was upgraded to an admin and I didn't encounter the same error during build again.